# Compiling GWT 2.7.0 against Errai 3.1.1.Final

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm trying to figure out if GWT 2.7.0 would compile against Errai 3.1.1.Final

My finding shows that it seems it won't compile. For I have an app with these versions:

```
<version.gwt>2.5.1</version.gwt>
<version.errai>3.0.0.Final</version.errai>
```

And that it compiles fine. The error with the 2.7.0 compilation is this:

```
[INFO]          Rule did not match
[INFO]          Found better fallback match for <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LoggerImplSevere'/>
[INFO]          Checking rule <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LoggerImplRegular'/>
[INFO]             Checking if all subconditions are true (<all>)
[INFO]                <when-type-is class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LoggerImplNull'/>
[INFO]                   Not an exact match
[INFO]                No: One or more subconditions was false
[INFO]          Rule did not match
[INFO]          Found better fallback match for <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LoggerImplRegular'/>
[INFO]          Checking rule <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImplRegular'/>
[INFO]             Checking if all subconditions are true (<all>)
[INFO]                <when-type-is class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImplNull'/>
[INFO]                   Not an exact match
[INFO]                No: One or more subconditions was false
[INFO]          Rule did not match
[INFO]          Found better fallback match for <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImplRegular'/>
[INFO]          Rebind result was com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.RequestImpl
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.520 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-23T11:37:03+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/328M
```

Comment: why downvote? I think this is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the release notes, 3.1.1.Final should work with 2.7.0: https://issues.jboss.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12310890&version=12326327

Comment: Not sure but somehow it works for me know. It could be that the problem was with Errai Validation inherits which prevented it to work